# Vim highlights everything in red after a functional line of code making the following lines of code not work

Tags: bash, vim, quoting

I have a tab separated text file e.g. `test.txt` containing ^M characters and a missing newline symbol at the end:

```
Samples  Factor
1        2
```

Using `tr` and thread https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-add-a-newline-to-the-end-of-a-file , I am able to process this table.

My problem is that in my script the line

```
tr '\r' '\n' < test.txt | sed -e '$a\' > test_temp
mv test_temp test.txt
```

makes everything below appear in "red" in `vim`, and my immediately following code does not run. If I remove the `sed -e '$a\'` part, everything works.

Do you have an explanation for this?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim seems to be incorrectly treating the backslash as special, even though backslashes don't do anything inside single quotes. What does `:set syntax` show? My Vim colors everything correctly with `syntax=sh`, so perhaps yours isn't treating your file as a shell script. (Interestingly, you may notice that Stack Overflow's syntax highlighter gets it wrong, too.)

If that's it, try adding a shebang line like `#!/bin/bash` up top.

Whatever it is, a simpler way to add a new line at the end is to simply echo one. It gets rid of the inefficiency of `sed` scanning through the entire input stream to find EOF.

```
{ tr '\r' '\n' < test.txt; echo; } > test_tmp
```

Comment: I tried the shebang, but it seems to still persist.

Answer (score -1):

The backslash in '$a\' prevents the last quote from ending the string, so it eats the rest of the script.  What are you trying to do with that sed command?

Comment: It doesn't, actually. Backslashes inside single quotes have no special meaning.

Comment: I have the problem, that the text file has a missing \n in the last line, making the shell prompt appear shifted when running "cat test.txt" and worse giving me 1 less line when running e.g. wc -l < text.txt